# Is this confusing TSQL syntax more efficient? Is it really that confusing?

Tags: sql-server

I would have searched but I don't even know how to search for something like this, so here goes.

I work in a company where I'm looking at lots of older stored procs (currently we're on  sql server 2012, I don't know when they were written, but likely 3-5+ years ago). I continually come across these little nuggets in select statements, and they are extremely confusing to me. Ultimately they are all math-based, so maybe there's a performance reason for these things? Maybe they are way more common than I thought, and I just haven't been exposed to them?

Here is an example, imagine it is buried in a SELECT clause, selecting from a table that has a numerical "balance" column (and please forgive me if my parens don't match up exactly ... you will get the idea).

```
SELECT 
  ...
  HasBalance = LEFT('Y', 1 * ABS(SIGN(SUM(balance)))) + LEFT('N', 1 * (1 -ABS(SIGN(SUM(balance)))))
  ...
```

I mean, it wasn't *that* hard to figure out that essentially what it's doing is coming up with 'Y' or 'N' by concat'ing 2 strings ('Y' + '') or ('' + 'N'), each of which were generated by using 3 functions to reduce a value (balance) to a 1 or 0 to multiply by 1 to determine how many characters to take in each LEFT function (ultimately, 0 or 1).

But come on.

Here is another example:

```
sum(x.amount * charindex('someCode', x.code) * charindex(x.code, 'someCode'))
```

This one is essentially saying x.code MUST equal 'someCode' or return 0; otherwise return x.amount. If either charindex fails it throws a *0 into the mix, 0'ing out the math.

There are lots of others, they're not impossible to figure out WHAT they're doing ... but I still have to spend time figuring out what they're doing.

Is the obscurity as obscure as I think it is? If so, is it worth the tradeoff (assuming there is a tradeoff)?

Thanks!

Comment: well, as you said, it isn't really very obscure. And I can't see a trade-off ¿, seems like just using a `CASE` expression would be enough

Comment: Thanks @Lamak; what I meant by "obscure" is: is this a common practice/trick that are well-known (which I've just never been exposed to)? Like, will a more experienced sql programmer take 1 look at that and go "oh yeah, it's the 'must-match-string' trick" or something.

Comment: i would highly doubt your last comment was the case. This is arguable, but i'd almost always trade off some performance for readability / maintainability. Granted, this is what comments are for, but it's unlikely that they wrote that code in that manner for performance reasons. I just can't imagine someone doing that much testing on each equation to see what shaves a second off.

Comment: @scsimon I agree that readability is (usually) better. Unfortunately, there were no comments here either. I doubt specialized testing happened for each function, I was wondering if it was more "general wisdom" that "_of course_ it's a better way" kind of a thing.